# Data Exploration - How To Bin Data?

Tags: data-visualization, nonlinear, binning

There are 1100 data points split into about 35 discrete groups and distributed towards the left.  After running a logistic regression which failed, then running it again by only predicting based on subsets of the data which worked, it seemed likely that there is a nonlinear relationship.

I am trying to determine the nature of this relationship to decide on how best to build my predictive model.  The first image below is each discrete value on the x axis, and the y axis is the percent of target variable success.

Since the first image doesn't reveal much I tried binning the data, so the three graphs below are the x variables binned into different groupings on the x axis, and the y axis is percent of the target variable success. It seems pretty hard to draw any conclusions as all these graphs show different things, or they don't show anything obvious, at least to me.

Question 1- How do I best decide on how to bin data, to show relationships?

Question 2- Are there any important relationships based on the graphs below that you can see?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you mean when you say "the nature of this relationship". Are you referring to the within group or between group relationships? Why did your original logistic regression fail? Are the 1100 data points split evenly between the 35 groups? Is this repeated measures data, if so have you explored mixed effects logistic regression. Providing more information on the study design setup and the data you are utilizing would be helpful. Or at least better than arbitrarily splitting out groups to make your models work.

Comment: William, I want to know how the DV reacts as the IV changes, with the goal of being able to create a more accurate predictive model.  The 1100 data points are not spread evenly; x has a range of 0:18 with .5 steps, there are the most data points around x=2.5,3, and then barely any around 18.  The below has more details.  Thanks so much for your help!

http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65523/logistic-regression-and-clustering/

Comment: Might I recommend presenting a bit more exploratory data analysis. In your first plot the x-axis is group, are the groups important, other than identifiers? What does the figure look like when the data are plotted on the 0-18 x-axis with varying colors to identify groups?

Comment: All four graphics suggest a nearly linear relationship between t[,2] and x. (Given the relatively narrow range of t[,2] this could be consistent with any of the standard links in logit regression: logit, probit, log, complementary log-log, and even a linear link.) It would help to size the dots to be proportional to the square roots of their bin counts, so that visual area is directly proportional to precision.

Comment: whuber, is it possible for this to be a linear relationship AND for the predictive model to do best only predicting on a subset of the training data most similar to the test case? What would make that possible?